# Proof of $\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{kn} \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Consider a bounded sequence $x_{n}$ of real numbers.
I want to proof that the $limsup$ of a subsequence $x_{kn}$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is smaller or equal to the $limsup$ of the mainsequence $x_{n}$ or in symbols:

$\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{kn} \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} x_{n}$.

I can see why this is correct, but don't know how to prove it. I think it is because $x_{kn}$ is a subsequence so if the mainsequence converges, so will the subsequence do, but I can't see how to fix it with the suprema.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a question of convergence. Limsup exists independent of convergence of $\{x_n\}$. What is the definition of limsup? What would happen if you put the definitions there, I think looking it from that angle could help you.

Comment: Every term in the subsequence shows up as a term in the sequence. It doesn't matter what your definition of limsup is, you just need to unpack the definition and apply this observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this weren't the case, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{k\to\infty} x_{n_k} > \limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n \doteq c,
\end{align*}
then for any $N$, we can find an $m(N) > N$ such that $x_{n_{m(N)}} > c+\varepsilon$. Since each $x_{n_{m(N)}}$ is a member of the original sequence, we have constructed a further subsequence $\{x_{n_{m(N)}}\}_{N=1}^{\infty}$ whose limit is strictly greater than $c$ (which by definition is the supremum of all subsequential limits).